# Laravel Cashier Stripe with duplicate payments

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I bought an application that uses Laravel Cashier Stripe to manage subscription payments, but it is duplicating payments and subscriptions for new users, does anyone know how to solve this problem?